# Prevent my app from taking the focus

Tags: .net, winforms, winapi

Our program listens for WM_COPYDATA message from a third party application in the WndProc. After receiving another version of the application every time that we receive WM_COPYDATA our program takes the focus from whatever application is the user working on. 
I tried ignoring WM_ACTIVATE and doing nothing when WM_COPYDATA comes but still my app gets the focus. I'm sure that their application activates ours but they are denying it. Is there any way to prevent my app from taking the focus?

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) 
    {
        if(m.Msg == WM_ACTIVATE)
            return;
        if(m.Msg == WM_COPYDATA)
        {
        //  ProcessCopyData(m);
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

UPDATE

I wrote the Focused property and the message values just before becoming Active

```
sw.WriteLine( this.Focused+"   " + m.ToString());
```

> False   msg=0x1c (WM_ACTIVATEAPP) hwnd=0x2606d4 wparam=0x1 lparam=0x0 result=0x0
>   False   msg=0x86 (WM_NCACTIVATE) hwnd=0x2606d4 wparam=0x0 lparam=0x0 result=0x0
>   False   msg=0x6 (WM_ACTIVATE) hwnd=0x2606d4 wparam=0x1 lparam=0x0 result=0x0

True   msg=0x281 (WM_IME_SETCONTEXT) hwnd=0x2606d4 wparam=0x1 lparam=0xffffffffc000000f result=0x0

This didn't work either

```
if(m.Msg == WM_NCACTIVATE || m.Msg == WM_ACTIVATE || m.Msg == WM_ACTIVATEAPP)
{
    m.WParam = (IntPtr)0;
}
```

Its possible to ignore any of these messages?

Comment: why not perform the listening on a dedicated background service that cannot be focused?

Comment: @Banana our application has user interface and does other things also.

Comment: yes i understand this, what i meant was create a dedicated service that will do the listening and control your GUI application. that way with the service in the middle, you can filter out unwanted messages...

Comment: There is no reason whatsoever why WM_COPYDATA would bring your app window into the foreground, other than you coding it that way or the other app that sends it being entirely too helpful.  With the latter explanation an obvious one for why you cannot find the reason.  Simply hiding your window is a workaround.  So is a telephone.

Comment: @HansPassant I tried hidden but it still gets the focus. I added the messages that I receive after wm_copydata

Comment: There's something that we cannot see. What you've described doesn't add up.

Comment: @JimMischel They have a virtual printer software. When I print from notepad to their printer they run a process that activates my application and I lose focus from notepad.

Comment: You need to start up Spy++ (in the Visual Studio Tools folder) and trace where the messages are coming from.